# How do I increase the size of the icons in a list stack?

Tags: finder, dock

When adding a folder to the dock to make a stack, I like to view it as a list. The only problem is, the size of the icons is too small. I know there is a way to change the size for the grid stack, but it doesn't seem to work on the list stack. Is it possible to change the size?

[image: The grid stack]

[image: The list stack]